# Клик по динамически созданым элементам вызывает множественную отправку на сервер

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
<div class="ddl-container" id="ddl_material">
                <div class="ddl-cont-item">акрил, металл</div>
                <div class="ddl-cont-item">бархат, картон</div>
                <div class="ddl-cont-item">бумага</div>
        </div>
```

ddl-cont-item - элементы с этим классом появляются на странице динамически. Мне нужно кликнув по одному из них отправить запрос на сервер.

```
 //убрать еденицу фильтра по матералам
    $(document.body).on('click', '.ddl-cont-item', function (event) {
        var removeItem = $(this).text();
        var selector = $(".ddl-cont-item");
      //функция заполняет массив строк postData.Materials для отправки на сервер
       FillMaterialFilter(selector);
       //удаляем из массива элемент по которому щелкнули
        postData.Materials = $.grep(postData.Materials, function (value) {
            return value != removeItem;
        });

        $(this).detach();
        //отправляем аякс на сервак с получением данных
        RenderItems(postData);
    });
 function FillMaterialFilter(selector)
    {
        var mat = selector.toArray();
        for (var i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
            postData.Materials.push(mat[i].innerHTML);
        }
    }
function RenderPriceSlider(Min, Max, MinCatPrice, MaxCatPrice) {
        $('.range-slider').val(Min + ',' + Max);
        $('.range-slider').jRange({
            from: MinCatPrice,
            to: MaxCatPrice,
            step: 1,
            scale: [MinCatPrice, MaxCatPrice],
            format: '%s руб',
            width: 300,
            showLabels: true,
            isRange: true
        });
    }
function RenderItems(postData) {
        alert(postData.Materials.length+' коливо');
        $('#gifLoader').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/products/allproducts",
            type: "POST",
            data: postData,
            //error: function () { alert("server error in render items"); },
            success: function (dataout) {
                $('#prodList').html(dataout);
                RenderPriceSlider(minPrice, maxPrice, MinCatPrice, MaxCatPrice);
                $('#gifLoader').hide();
            }
        });
    }



    var page = $('#pageFromProds').val();
    var CatId = $('#CatId').val();
    var MinCatPrice = $('#MinCatPrice').val();
    var MaxCatPrice = $('#MaxCatPrice').val();
    var MinPrice = $('#MinPrice').val();
    var MaxPrice = $('#MaxPrice').val();
    var postData =
    {
        "CatId": CatId,
        "PageNumber": page,
        "PageProductCount": 0,
        "CatIdList": [],
        "QueryString": "",
        "MinCatPrice": MinCatPrice,
        "MaxCatPrice": MaxCatPrice,
        "MinPrice": MinPrice,
        "MaxPrice": MaxPrice,
        "Materials":[],
        "Nanesenie": [],
        "Color": [],
        "Brand": [],
        "Nalichie": [],
        "DownRankOrder": true,
        "UpPriceOrder": true
    }
```

Засада в том что все работает как бы красиво - внешне все улетает и прорисовывается как надо. Но в результате отладки я заметил что ЗАПРОС к базе -RenderItems(postData) выполняется ровно столько раз скока элементов динамических в контейнере  ddl-container. Этого не может вынести мое сердце, но как решить эту проблем?

Comment: уточните, сам метод `RenderItems` выполняется несколько раз, или внутри него запрос отправляется несколько раз? в данном коде не видно никаких предпосылок, чтобы данный метод выполнялся несколько раз.

Comment: добавил код остальных функций

Comment: Если три дива - щелкаю второй - в контроллер приходят перестановки первый, первый, третий;третий третий первый; и только потом первый третий - то что надо и базу дергает 3 раза -кошмар

Comment: нашел статью https://toddmotto.com/attaching-event-handlers-to-dynamically-created-javascript-elements/ вот думаю надо отдельно повесить событие на каждый див динамический,  - пробую

Comment: сложно у вас как то написан обработчик клика и т.п. там можно просто взять `$(this).siblings()`  а вы берете всех, пытаесь оттуда исключить текущий и т.п..

Comment: вообще убедитесь, что у вас только один обработчик навешивается на это все. и вместо `document.body` укажите `$(".ddl-container")`